# Problema al definir una función para algoritmo simple con python

Tags: python

Quería crear un algoritmo para que al poner un número del 1 al 12, este imprimiese por pantalla el mes del año correspondiente.

```py
mes? = ''
while mes not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split:
    mes? = input('Escribe un número del 1 al 12: ')

meses = 'enero febrero marzo abril mayo junio julio agosto septiembre octubre noviembre diciembre'.split

def obtener_mes(lista, x):
    return lista[x]

mes = obtener_mes(meses, mes?)

print(mes)
```

Sé que hay otras maneras de hacerlo, pero porque esta no funciona. ¿Acaso no se define así la función?

Answer (score 2):

La solución más simple es corregir los errores...
No se como trabajes, pero usar `?` es un error directo.
Segundo, debes agregar paréntesis al método `split()`
Tercero, debes convertir el input a int, dado que es un str al leerse, y para meterlo a una lista, debes incluirlo como int.

Aporte entregado por @Christian:

> Yo declararía la lista antes del while pues la operación '1 2 3 4 5 6
> 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split() se ejecuta nuevamente en cada repetición.

```
mes = ''
while mes not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split():
    mes = input('Escribe un número del 1 al 12: ')
    intMes = int(mes)

meses = 'enero febrero marzo abril mayo junio julio agosto septiembre octubre noviembre diciembre'.split()

def obtener_mes(meses, intMes):
    return meses[intMes]

mesElegido = obtener_mes(meses, intMes)

print(mesElegido)
```

Comment: Tanto un string como una lista es un iterable por lo que `"1" in "0123456789"` es lo mismo que `"1" in ["0", "1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7","8", "9"]`. pero claro el primer caso no es posible. Yo declararía la lista antes del `while` pues la operación `'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split()` se ejecuta nuevamente en cada repetición.

Comment: Ese consejo deberias darselo al OP XD

Comment: ay!, la pereza me invade. Si quieres puedes incluirlo en tu respuesta

Comment: hay de haber, ay! de queja... ya la agregué skdjkjsd

Comment: ay de queja xd.

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque:

1. usas un caracter no reconocido: `?`
2. para llamar el metodo `str.split()` requiere paréntesis
3. Al indexar `lista[x]`, sucede que x es de tipo `str` y para indexar lista debería ser typo `int`